# Unusual Error when Django App Is Deployed on apache2+mod_wsgi

Tags: django, django-models

I'm getting this weird `AttributeError` on the app I'm currently working on. I'm developing using the development web server i.e. "runserver" command of django toolsets. Then I decided to test the application on **apache+mod-wsgi** and I persistently get this error though it works fine sometimes. So I think there must be something wrong with that piece of code,

---

*so I decided to **comment it out** and see what happens. And **YES**, it still give me the same error (See 2nd picture).* <-- NOT RELEVANT NOW. **The AttributeError I'm getting on custom User model, even if it actually contains the `classmethod get_by_type_and_id()` is what I'm interested on.**

---

Have you even seen like this one before? What do you think is causing this? I've followed the tutorial [here](http://www.lennu.net/2012/05/14/django-deployement-installation-to-ubuntu-12-dot-04-server/) to deploy it. Note though that `User`  is not the built-in django `User` model. I think it's a "customized,stripped-down" implementation based from the django's `Auth` module.

**Note that I have not gotten this error on my development using django's own development server. This only happens when I deployed the app on Apache+mod_wsgi.**

**More Info:**

Django version == 1.2.5

Thanks! I'd really appreciate any kind of help.

First Picture:
 [image: AttributeError]

2nd Picture:
[image: The code which even commented out, still produce an error]

Comment: which django version you are using? And how you have extended your user model?

Comment: django 1.2.5, the app is not using django's built-in User model from its Auth module. It's using a customized one, but I think is still based from Django's own auth module.

Comment: any reason why you are using so outdated version of django?

Comment: unfortunately, it's what the app I'm working on is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of diving into the code, I had a eureka moment. So I thought, maybe at some point `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model is being put into action by some django module used in the application. Because like I mentioned, this app's User model is customized and the application is not using `django.contrib.auth.*` at least directly. This was my suspicion because this kind of error is not specific to that particular attribute. Sometimes it gets through that point, but then another AttributeError  would occur on some other view referring to other User model attributes. Then at one point I noticed that the attributes of User in the error messages was that of django.contrib.auth.models.User.

So I decided to "remove" django.contrib.auth.models on my python path, and there it showed, an error occurred in one of the modules I'm using specifically `django.contrib.messages`. I removed it, and I'm not seeing the AttributeError again. It turned out that django's `Message` model has a foreign_key to django.contrib.auth.models.User.

But then, I lost the flexibility of django message framework, especially when I'm using it on view with a HttpResponseRedirect i.e. no way to put useful messages in a template's context. or maybe there is? :)

**UPDATE 2 (Pretty Sure Now):**

Yes, I'm pretty sure now that `django.contrib.messages` is the one causing the error. I tried reproducing the error on another application which uses the customized User model i.e. not django.contrib.auth.models.User. I enabled django.contrib.messages module and produced basically the same error. I would like to know why is this happening on Apache+mod_wsgi, but not on django's own development server.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to notice:

- Are you sure that you have `get_by_type_and_id` method for the User?
- You set `pasword` instead of `password` (typo)
- I think you have to indent line 60 in your second screenshot

Comment: 1. yes, i'm sure.
2. ooh yes, just a typo. but i reverted to the original code.
3. yes, great catch. but like i said, i reverted to the original code. the AttributeError on get_by_type_and_id was already showing even before I commented it out and replaced by a direct call on User's object manager.

Comment: yes, another question. do you have to restart apache, whenever you change some files on an application?

Comment: I think you don't have to restart apache but you have to restart wsgi.

Comment: oh you could do that? i'm only been directly working with apache. the only part where i come across wsgi is on virtual host configuration file.

Comment: If you look at the list of processes in your OS you'll notice one for apache and another for WSGI. But if you launch only apache then it seems that apache loads wsgi itself so you have to restart apache.